# Update UI after language change on NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, ios7, internationalization

I created a language selection screen, where the user is able to select the preferred language of the app (iPad).

I commit the language change like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

It works perfectly, except that it needs the app to be restarted for the UI to take the new language setting. According to Apple's docs:

> To detect when changes to a preference value occur, apps can also
>   register for the notification NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification. The
>   shared NSUserDefaults object sends this notification to your app
>   whenever it detects a change to a preference located in one of the
>   persistent domains. You can use this notification to respond to
>   changes that might impact your user interface. For example, you could
>   use it to detect changes to the user’s preferred language and update
>   your app content appropriately.

So it looks like I need to register for the notification NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification and update my UI. Which class shoult listen to the notification? Any idea what the code look like? My app is based on SKScenes and Sprite Kit objects, instead of xib and UIViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

All notifications can be detected by watching NSNotificationCenter:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(userDefaultsChange:)  
           name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];

- (void)userDefaultsChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
     //update UI to new language here
}
```

Addobserver when you create your class and remember you have to remove it when class is removed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer. Whilst they are allowed answers that just provide code and don't explain themselves aren't very good answers. By the way I understand more for the the person who has asked because if they understood they wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I added some description, I don't really think it was necessary but I explained a bit

Comment: If they understood what they were doing then they wouldn't be asking the question. So just providing code doesn't tell them anything and doesn't help them learn. Lets put it this way if you asked a question about some code that wasn't working and you didn't understand it and I just gave you some code and didn't explain it would you learn from that even though you still don't understand the code???

Comment: Thanks @GrzegorzKrukowski. But, how can I update the UI taking into account the new language?
I'm looking for the implementation of the comment: //update UI to new language here
I would like the SKSpriteNodes and every other object that is localised (images, strings), which are initialised with: initWithImageNamed or nslocalizedstring to be redrawn using the new language setting.